# Spring boot repackage: Jar task not repackaged (didn't match withJarTask)

Tags: grails, gradle, spring-boot

I have a new Grails 3.1.7 project compiled by gradle wrapper. The project is just the base project created by: grails create-app

When I run:
    ./gradlew --info clean jar bootRepackage

I see the following output during the last part of the build

```
:jar (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:jar
Executing task ':jar' (up-to-date check took 0.023 secs) due to:
  Output file /var/jenkins_home/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/helloworld-0.1.jar has changed.
  Output file /var/jenkins_home/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/helloworld-0.1.jar has been removed.
:jar (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.259 secs.
:findMainClass (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:findMainClass
Executing task ':findMainClass' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
:findMainClass (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.041 secs.
:war (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:war
Executing task ':war' (up-to-date check took 0.039 secs) due to:
  Output file /var/jenkins_home/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/helloworld-0.1.war has changed.
  Output file /var/jenkins_home/workspace/helloworld/build/libs/helloworld-0.1.war has been removed.
:war (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 4.305 secs.
:bootRepackage (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:bootRepackage
Executing task ':bootRepackage' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Jar task not repackaged (didn't match withJarTask): task ':jar'
Jar task not repackaged (didn't match withJarTask): task ':pathingJar'
Jar task not repackaged (didn't match withJarTask): task ':pathingJarCommand'
Setting mainClass: helloworld.Application
:bootRepackage (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.94 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

What is happening in the repackage task?

What does this mean?

```
Jar task not repackaged (didn't match withJarTask): task ':jar'
```

gradle.properties:

```
grailsVersion=3.1.7
gradleWrapperVersion=2.13
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.6"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "helloworld"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.7"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

The code for this example is at: https://github.com/liftyourgame/helloworld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prior to grails-3.1.5, the `bootRepackage` task has processed all jar tasks which was undesired for pathing jars.

now it processes only the `war` task if the `War` plugin is applied (by default).

also, a `gradle(w) assemble` (which is also used by `grails war`, for example) builds only a war (no jar) artefact if the `War` plugin is applied. the same applies to spring-boot.

but that is usually just fine because the war is also executable (i.e. `java -jar my.war`).

so if you really want to build that jar artefact and that should be subject to repackaging, reconfigure the `bootRepackage` task accordingly:

```
bootRepackage.withJarTask = jar
```

however - if there is no good reason against it - i would say its better to stick to the war file and use that as executable. or remove the `War` plugin which makes `assemble` and `bootRepackage` default to build/process the jar artefact.